# Calling api function in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, coldfusion

I'm trying to make a call to a url to get a json object returned.

I have an example in coldfusion i am trying to use to base it off of.

```
Test For IPCorg123: (the return should: Hello World)<br>
<cfinvoke method="test20130401" returnvariable="rawReturn" 
webservice="https://secure.test.com/webservices/ws_users.cfc?wsdl">   
    <cfinvokeargument name="accountlogincode" value="1"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="accountxmlcode" value="1"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="accountidspecialcode" value="1"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="authorlogin" value="1"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="authorpassword" value="1"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="TestString" value="Hello World/>
</cfinvoke>
<cfdump var="#rawReturn#"><br><br><br><br>
Done!
```

I'm trying to convert this to c# and heres what I have.

```
class Program
{
    public static string accountlogincodename = "accountlogincodevalue";
    public static string accountxmlcodename = "accountxmlcodevalue";
    public static string accountidspecialcodename = "accountidspecialcode";
    public static string authorloginname = "authorlogin";
    public static string authorpasswordname = "authorpassword";
    public static string TestStringname = "TestString";

    public static string accountlogincodevalue = "1";
    public static string accountxmlcodevalue = "1";
    public static string accountidspecialcodevalue = "1";
    public static string authorloginvalue = "1";
    public static string authorpasswordvalue = "1";
    public static string TestStringvalue = "Hello";

    static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://secure.test.com/webservices/ws_users.cfc?wsdl");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpRequestMessage m = new HttpRequestMessage();
            m.Properties.Add(accountlogincodename, accountlogincodevalue);
            m.Properties.Add(accountxmlcodename, accountxmlcodevalue);
            m.Properties.Add(accountidspecialcodename, accountidspecialcodevalue);
            m.Properties.Add(authorloginname, authorloginvalue);
            m.Properties.Add(authorpasswordname, authorpasswordvalue);
            m.Properties.Add(TestStringname, TestStringvalue);

            // New code:
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(m);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var x = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting the expected result back, which is just "Hello World"

Comment: You need to tell us what the webservice endpoint (`https://secure.test.com/webservices/ws_users.cfc?wsdl`) actually expects. ColdFusion uses the WSDL scheme to build the request, which you did not include in your post.

Comment: It's in the cold fusion portion. The xsdl link is in the cold fusion portion on the webservice argument. Are you talking about a different part?

Comment: Duh, I didn't expect `secure.test.com` to be the real domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to call it is to add a Service Reference.

In the Solution Explorer right click **References** then add Service Reference.

**[image: Advanced]**

On the Add service Reference dialog Click on Advanced
[image]

Then click on Add Web Reference
[image]

Enter the URL adding the WSDL: "https://secure.test.com/webservices/ws_users.cfc?wsdl"

[image]

Then Click **Add Reference**
[image]

Finally in your code you can call the method like this:

```
com.test.secure.Ws_usersService ws = new com.test.secure.Ws_usersService();

var result = ws.test20130401(accountlogincodevalue, accountxmlcodevalue, accountidspecialcodevalue, authorloginvalue, authorpasswordvalue, TestStringvalue);
```

Right now is returning : **Fail|Could Not Validate Authenticity**  i guess you have to pass it real credentials in order to authenticate.

Hope this help!